# Fastest way to delete rows in QTableWidget for QT C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qt6

I want to delete rows in `QTableWidget` between a range.
The only problem here is that deleting row by row...takes very long time.

Is there a way to make this faster by deleting between a range? I want to delete rows from `toRow` to `fromRow`, where `toRow > fromRow`

```
/* Create progress bar */
QProgressDialog progress("Loading table...", "Abort loading", fromRow, toRow, this);
progress.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality::ApplicationModal);

/* Delete */
if(database->deleteRowsBetweenID(fromID, toID)){
    /* Remove each row */
    for(int i = toRow; i >= fromRow; i--){
        ui->measurementTableWidget->removeRow(i);

        /* Break the process */
        if (progress.wasCanceled())
            break;
        else
            progress.setValue(toRow - i);
    }

    /* Close the progress bar */
    progress.setValue(toRow);
```

Comment: What about [QTableWidget::clear()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#clear) or [QTableWidget::clearContents()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#clearContents)?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat No. That would delete all.

Comment: I saw this coming. The _where toRow is the bottom of the QTableWidget and fromRow is the beginning of the table._ is a bit confusing...

Comment: How about accessing the inside model of the view. There is for sure something to remove ranges...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yes. I was writing wrong here.

Comment: Found it: [QAbstractItemModel::removeRows()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRows). Please note, in the case of a table, you can ignore the last param. `QModelIndex`. (It's more important for tree view.) To retrieve the inside model, you can use [QTableWidget::model()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#model).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat So if I use `row = 500` and then `count = 10`, then I'm going to delete from `500` to `510` ?

Comment: Yes. The rows are enumerated. The first is 0. (...if I remember right)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat It's working. Thank you for the answer, if you will post one.